# Chi Square Analysis Throws Error - The internally computed table of expected frequencies has a zero element at (0,)

Tags: machine-learning, python, chi-squared-test, inference, scipy

I am trying to see the association between two variables. I used Chi-Square analysis in Scipy package in Python.

Here is the crosstab result of the two variables:

```
pd.crosstab(data['loan_default'],data['id_proofs'])
```

Result:

```
   id_proofs    2   3   4   5
  loan_default              
    0   167035  15232   273 3
    1   46354   4202    54  1
```

If I apply the Chi-Square on the same data, I see an error saying `ValueError: The internally computed table of expected frequencies has a zero element at (0,).`

Code:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
stat,p,dof,expec = chi2_contingency(data['loan_default'],data['id_proofs'])
print(stat,p,dof,expec)
```

Error Report:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-63c6f49aec48> in <module>()
      1 from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
----> 2 stat,p,dof,expec = chi2_contingency(data['loan_default'],data['id_proofs'])
      3 print(stat,p,dof,expec)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/contingency.py in chi2_contingency(observed, correction, lambda_)
    251         zeropos = list(zip(*np.where(expected == 0)))[0]
    252         raise ValueError("The internally computed table of expected "
--> 253                          "frequencies has a zero element at %s." % (zeropos,))
    254 
    255     # The degrees of freedom

ValueError: The internally computed table of expected frequencies has a zero element at (0,).
```

What could be the reasons for the issue? How can I overcome this?

Comment: Does the variable "id_proofs" have the ability to take a value other than 2,3,4,5? Like could it potentially be 1 (even though it isn't 1 in the sample)?

Comment: There is presumably documentation of this code. It's a little surprising that some experienced Python user has not chipped in (apologies to @Glen_b if he is one; I know much about your tastes but not that detail).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you called the routine incorrectly. I've never used Python, but that is my guess: I'd expect a chi-square routine to want input of a frequency table, although I have written one that does the counting too from the raw data.

Or there is a bug, which I would think highly unlikely. Enough people should have banged on this already (a standard problem, much used language) to shake out simple bugs. In quite different software (`tabchii` in Stata, but that's immaterial otherwise) I get this (assuming that I am interpreting this correctly as a 2 x 4 table)

```
. tabchii   167035  15232   273 3 \  46354   4202    54  1

          observed frequency
          expected frequency

------------------------------------------------------
          |                    col                    
      row |         1          2          3          4
----------+-------------------------------------------
        1 |    167035      15232        273          3
          |  1.67e+05  15215.440    256.018      3.132
          | 
        2 |     46354       4202         54          1
          | 46320.589   4218.560     70.982      0.868
------------------------------------------------------

2 cells with expected frequency < 5
1 cell with expected frequency < 1

         Pearson chi2(3) =   5.3288   Pr = 0.149
likelihood-ratio chi2(3) =   5.6733   Pr = 0.129
```

Hence the smallest expected frequency is 0.868. While it's much, much less than the largest expected frequency, there should be no difficulty in working with a table like that.